# How to add clickable hyperlinks for email id, website, telephone in mail signature designed using Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, e-mail

One of my colleague had created a signature for the company using Adobe Illustrator. Now the head of our company wants clickable links to be present in the signature so that one should be able to click on the links and forwarded to the desired destination like email id, website, telephone, etc. The signature presently created is an pdf and jpeg format. How can we add clickable links to the signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An e-mail signature should not be just an image. Don't forget that lots of people have images turned off in their e-mails by default, unless they press a button (which most won't do). Moreover, having the contact info there as (copyable) text is a huge plus that an image lacks.

Technically, I guess it's possible to make an html signature with just your image and a heatmap for the actual links, but this is far from wise. Most e-mail clients will not be able to parse the heatmap, in addition to the copyability issue mentioned above.

I'd say convert it all to html -- the simplest kind possible. Keep only actual images as such, and type out text as, well, text. That way, it's easy to place an `<a>` tag around it for a clickable link.

Lastly, I don't think a *.pdf as an e-mail signature is ever going to work: the contents of the *.pdf aren't visible when you open the e-mail, you'll have to open the *.pdf separately. Again, most users won't do this. Personally, I'd feel quite annoyed if all I got for my trouble of opening was your contact info - which should already be present in your actual mail without any extra effort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to convert illustrator file to html as we have already created signatures for all the employees?

Comment: Welcome. Not that I know of. I guess you'll just have to code it by hand, or have a developer do so.

Comment: @Javerd Ahmed, you can make the ai files into an svg(Scalable vector graphic) and use them as great web images. I forgot to mention, they are 100% scalable and can even select elements inside the file!

Comment: Thanks everyone. What I have done is I made slices of each part where I need to provide hyperlink, then saved the ai file for web in html format. Once the html file was created I edited it to add <a> tag around the division. Special thanks to @Bakabaka for giving the perfect answer.

Answer (score -3):

Having some experience with this myself, I agree, Bakabaka is completely right.  You don't want your email signature to be a single image - you run the risk of it being stripped out by aggressive security filters, but also, spam filters don't like those images and worse that your sig being stripped out - your message may never arrive because it's been caught as spam - that has a whole mess of other implications.

The best method is 1990's style, basic HTML markdown - reducing the divs and spans and tables, which spam filters look at closely.

[Emailsignature.com](http://www.emailsignature.com) renders their sigs this way - and you can manage them centrally for everyone/anyone in your company.  We use them (their cloud version) for that and peer-to-peer email campaigns.

Comment: You have already linked to your site in a question that was unrelated. This does not solve the problem, we are looking for solutions on how to fix this, not paid services. I will not delete this answer, but please don't post this link unless it actually fixed the issues stated by the people asking. Also, links are no-follow.